# Query to find all the providers that offer all the services

Tags: t-sql

Let's say we have a provider_service table that stores all the services offered by providers.

Provider_Service Table: ProviderID | ServiceId

Then we have a table_valued parameter @idServices with a list of services.

I need a query for SQLSERVER to find all the providers that offer all the services specified in the table valued parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ps.ProviderID
    FROM Provider_Service ps
        INNER JOIN @idServices i
            ON ps.ServiceId = i.ServiceId
    GROUP BY ps.ProviderID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ps.ServiceId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @idServices)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. ( In my case I don't need the DISTINCT because ProviderID,ServiceID is a unique key)

Comment: @sil The `HAVING` guarantees that *all* of the services in the table-valued parameter are found in the main table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ps.* 
FROM Provider_Service ps
INNER JOIN @idServices s ON s.ServiceId = ps.ServiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question and assuming the field in the TVP is ServiceId, it's simply an inner join between the two

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Provider_Service PS
    INNER JOIN
        @idServices IS
        ON IS.ServiceId = PS.ServiceId
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is double negation: all providers for which no service exists that is not serviced by that provider.  In SQL:

```
select  distinct ps1.ProviderID
from    Provider_Service ps1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from   @idServices is
        where  not exists
               (
               select  *
               from   Provider_Service ps2
               where  ps2.ProviderID = ps1.ProviderID
                      ps2.ServiceId = is.ServiceID
               )
        )
```